# What Apache config do I need for Artifactory Docker support?

Tags: apache-2.2, docker

The Artifactory Docker documentation shows how to configure nginx as a reverse proxy but what's the equivalent Apache2 configuration?

In particular what are the apache equivalents of the following statements and are they necessary?

- client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
- chunked_transfer_encoding on; # required to avoid HTTP 411: see Issue #1486 (https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1486)

http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories#DockerRepositories-ConfiguringaReverseProxy

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName artprod.company.com 

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/artprod.company.com.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/artprod.company.com.key

        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost on

        ProxyPass / http://artprod.company.com:8080/artifactory/api/docker/<repository key>
        ProxyPassReverse / http://artprod.company.com:8080/artifactory/api/docker/<repository key>
</VirtualHost>
```